# Laravel - Many to many polymorphic Reations - Get, Update, Delete With Additional Fields

Tags: php, laravel

I set up my project like this using many to many polymorphic relationships.

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

book_pages
    id - integer
    book_id - integer

contents
    id - integer
    detail - string
    url - string

contentable
    id - integer
    content_id - integer
    contentable_id - integer
    contentable_type - string
    left - string
    top - string
```

Same content can be on multiple book pages or posts. Book pages and posts can have multiple contents. But this relation has its own properties ('left', 'top'->position of this content in the book page or post).

I can save left and top fields using this:

```
$book_page->contents()->attach($content, ['left' => $left, 'top' => $top]);
```

But when I want to retrieve contents using 'with'; can't get left and top properties.

```
BookPage::where('id', $id)->with('contents')->first();
```

The result is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "book_id": 6,
  "contents": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "detail": null,
      "url": "audio.mp3"
    }
  ]
}
```

- I want to get 'left' and 'top' too.
- I want to update this relation's 'left' and 'top' while updating this content.
- And also I want to delete this specific relation not the content.

I don't want to use DB:: and join. Can I do this with Eloquent.

Comment: it should be the same as many to many relationship, add ->withPivot('left', 'top') to the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@anurat-chapanond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264017/anurat-chapanond) mentioned I added `->withPivot('left', 'top')` relation to BookPage model. This is the last state of Model:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Content::class, 'contentable')->withPivot('left', 'top');
}
```

After that addition Eloquent worked. Result of `BookPage::where('id', $id)->with('contents')->first();` is now:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "book_id": 6,
  "contents": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "detail": null,
      "url": "audio.mp3"
      "pivot": {
        "contentable_id": 1,
        "content_id": 5,
        "contentable_type": "App\\Models\\BookPage",
        "left": 10,
        "top": 22
      }
    }
  ]
}
```